# In a population of 160 doctors and pharmacist working in a certain hospital?

Tags: probability-theory

Can anyone help me in this problem , please ?

[image]
MY try

1) $\frac {49}{160}=0.30625$

2)$\frac {90}{160}=0.5625$

3)$\frac {47}{160}=0.29375$

4)$\frac {23}{49}=0.4694$

Is my work right?

Thank you very much

Comment: no 2) is has *n*ever smoked.  Not has ever smoked.

Comment: But other than that it seems good.  You should give details of how you did you work.

Comment: @fleablood  ; yes  you are right  , $26+64=90$ ; answer is $90/160$ which is $C $

Answer (score 1):

The picture is a bit confusing, but here is how I think it is meant to be interpreted:  there are three regions, which represent

1. 47 pharmacists who have ever smoked,
2. 23 doctors who have smoked, and
3. 64 non-doctors (pharmacists) who have never smoked.

The total population is 160 people.  The number of doctors who have never smoked can be computed using inclusion-exclusion, which gives a count for each cell of the completed Venn diagram.  From that, all of the desired probabilities can be computed.

Comment: The picture changed!

Answer (score 1):

If we let $d$ be the number of doctors who have never smoked, then the answers will look like the following:

[5] $\frac{d+23}{160}$

[6] $\frac{d + 64}{160}$

[7] $\frac{47}{160}$

[8] $\frac{23}{d+23}$

You can figure out $d$ by subtracting the total number of pharmacists as well as the $23$ doctors who have smoked from the total population. (Supposing we read the Venn Diagram like Xander mentioned previously)